# Sub-commands in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to create a cli in bash that allows a user to be able to fetch a list of database instances on our platform. I want them to be able to type in something like:

```
$ dbinv instances show --environment=all
```

Equally, if they want to look at the users of a specific instance called db1, they might type:

```
$ dbinv instances users show --environment=production --instance=db1
```

How would one go about developing this from a cli perspective. What should I be researching or exploring?

Should I be looking at something like Ruby or Python, rather than bash?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! IMHO, your question is too broad for this site. You can implement your requirements in multiple ways and in many languages. Nothing in your question limits your choices. I voted to close this question because it is "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use all 3 languages. I would recommend looking to see how svn, hg, git, docker do it.

They will have a wrapper command: e.g.
`dbinv`.
It will look at its 1st argument, and then call a helper script. e.g.
`dbinv show arg1`, will call `«directory-containing-dbinv-commands»/dbinv-show arg1`.

This wrapper can easily be done in bash. The sub-commands can be done in other languages (use a `#!` at the top of a script to specify the language).

To do the wrapper, look-up `"$1"`, `"$@"`, `shift` and `exec`(not as important).